# Accessing QGIS Plugin repositories from behind Proxy

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, proxy

I have been trying to teach myself QGIS by using this forum and others to help. Most of my questions can be answered by downloading plugins that are available through 3rd party repositories but for some reason I am not able to connect with these. Anyone have any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: In Qgis, Plugins>Fetch Python Plugins, click the Repositories tab. What is the "Status" that you see there for existing repositories?

Comment: On the Respositories tab the status is 'unavailable'. Clicking 'Add 3rd party repositories' makes no difference.

Comment: are you behind a proxy? I do get that error while i am...

Comment: i work in the NHS so probably...

Comment: Please use a Comment rather than an Answer for a comment like this.  However, if you were going to detail some steps you took in order to answer your own Question then that would be acceptable as an Answer which you could then Accept to finalise the question.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I have used @AndreJ 's solution it works just perfect for me. Thumbs up buddy!

Answer (score 23):

I was able to set up proxy settings in QGIS (Settings->Options->Network) so that it could communicate through our proxy server. In my case, the Default proxy type didn't work--I had to use HTTPProxy. Once that was done, I had no problem getting to the plugins on the repo servers.

Comment: I am behind a firewall and Hawken answer worked for me...Thanks

Comment: also need restart Qgis. Thx)

Comment: I restarted Qgis, but it didn't work until I cleared the cache (I guess). Go to Settings > Options > Network > Cache Settings > Authentication > Clear authentication connection cache

Answer (score 11):

Here is a workaround if you are behind proxy and not getting the repositories. This would work for all python plugins.

1. Download the plugin directly from the repository url using your
   browser. For example, for CadTools, download the zip file from the
   here [repo link](http://pyqgis.org/contributed/cadtools.zip)
2. Unzip the file. Copy the folder(usually one directory down the
   extracted folder) to your python plugins directory. In windows, this
   would be for QGIS1: `C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python\plugins`, for QGIS2: `C:\Users\yourusername\.qgis2\python\plugins` or for QGIS3: `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins` and on OSX: `~/.qgis/python/plugins`
3. Restart QGIS and now you can see this plugin installed. Just enable this plugin in the Plugin Manager.

Comment: And in OSX the directory is `~/.qgis/python/plugins`

Comment: In vinayan's step #1, you can access the repository urls, by double-clicking on a listed repository and copy/pasting its .xml url to your browser. Many of the repositories have a .xsl stylesheet that renders the plugin listings as HTML. For example: http://www.faunalia.it/qgis/plugins.xml If the repository does not have a stylesheet, have a look at the .xml source in your browser for the download links.

Comment: Update for QGIS 2.0 and later: the target path is `C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins`, and the repository is now https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/

Comment: For QGIS 3 it will be: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins

Answer (score 2):

If you are running QGIS from behind some firewall/proxy setups, you can't get the repositories.  I have the same issue when running QGIS behind a restrictive firewall via a proxy at work, but no problem when running QGIS from home.

Comment: You can get the repos! See my answer for more details. Basically a restart is required.

Comment: This is perhaps a change since I posted this answer almost six years ago.

Answer (score 2):

On your QGIS go to

> settings >> options >>network

Then check the  "Use proxy for web access" box

> set the proxy type to be defaultProxy to use the system proxy

That way, whatever proxy seetings you have will be inherited and you won't have to insert again.

Answer (score 1):

Running QGIS 2.18.12.

- Configure the Proxy in `Settings > Options > Network`. (As others have pointed out.)
- Select `Use proxy for web access`.
- (For me):
   Proxy type: `HttpProxy`
   Host:  `my-proxy-url.foo` (No leading `https://`)
   Port:  `3128`.
   User/Password: *empty*.
- **Verify** that it works: `Help > Check QGIS Version`.
- **Restart** QGIS.
- Now, go to `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins`.
- Success: Plugin repository gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with not being able to connect to official repository but found how to fix this. I replaced DHCP with a static IP address and QGIS now connects to repository. How to here: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/