# How to install PostGIS and OpenLayers plugins?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, postgis, google-maps

I am new to QGIS and have installed the QGIS v 2.2.0.

For adding google map as a base layer I need to install OpenLayers plugin. I also need to add the PostGIS plugin for DB management purpose.

Can anyone guide me how to add/install the plugins OpenLayers and PostGIS to QGIS 2.2.0?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to GIS Stackexchange.  In general all plugins are installed via `Plugins->Manage and Install Plugins`.  Once the dialog box opens, Just start typing 'OpenLayers' in the search box and you'll see the list available plugins narrow until you can find the one you want.

For PostGIS, QGIS 2.2. already comes with PostGIS connectivity capabilities out of the box.  There are some additional plugins relating to PostGIS such as PGRouting and you can find/install these in the same way as described above.

Comment: Thank for the help....I am not able to find the OpenLayers plugin while searching..

Answer (score 0):

At the QGIS Site you can find your answer:

http://qgis.org/de/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html#managing-plugins

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but the Get More option in plugin manager window is not there..

Comment: In this case you might not have Internet access, or you are hiding behind a proxy.

Comment: Yes, I need to provide proxy authentication while accessing the internet...

Comment: Maybe you will find a solution here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25188/how-to-access-qgis-plugin-repositories-from-behind-a-proxy

Comment: Yes..I have done the proxy setting and its working now..thanks