# What should i do if the Repository tab "Status" was indicating "unavailable".? (using proxy server)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, plugins

In the plug in Repository tab. The "Status" was indicating "unavailable". I tried ["hawkens"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25188/how-to-access-qgis-plugin-repositories-from-behind-a-proxy?lq=1) suggestion about the HTTPproxy thing but it didn't work (the network that I am using is a proxy server).

Any suggestion please? I'm trying hard to get the proxy host number and the port (is it the number on the host and port?)

Comment: Did you try the method posted by @vinayan from the same post by downloading/installing the plugins manually? Or is it necessary to connect through the proxy?