# Valid hosted GeoJSON format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson

I am looking to work with *hosted* GeoJSON data within QGIS. I have read a number of posts, such as [add GeoJSON content in QGIS](http://webgeodatavore.com/add-geojson-content-in-qgis-short-recipes.html) that shows very easily how to load GeoJSON into QGIS. I have had limited success with this process, however, for the most part I have not been able to consistently load hosted GeoJSON data into QGIS. I have tested with a few sources, including hosting my own data in Github with the same results (see the link below). I repeatedly get a not a valid data source error on load. My question, is there a standard for hosted GeoJSON data in order to load into QGIS, or are there settings that must be configured within QGIS?

https://github.com/ryangarnett/geodata/blob/master/locations.geojson

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is your link points to a web page on github, you need to link to the raw content. if you use **curl** on that url you'll see html content coming back.

if you click the 'raw' button on the Github page you'll get https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryangarnett/geodata/master/locations.geojson

Just tried this in qgis 2.18.7, loading with the 'protocol'/'geojson' setting and it loads fine.

**EDIT** If it works at home but not at work, check with your IT people. It may be that they're using a proxy. Typically browsers get set up to work with a proxy, but they may not have done that for QGIS. You can set this up in **Settings > Network > Use a proxy for web access**. A quick way to check is to try opening the plugin manager in your work setting. If it fails to connect, it's probably a proxy issue. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28706/55203) for suggested settings.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I cannot seem to replicate. I used the same URL and process. Only difference...QGIS 2.18.6 and potentially different encoding. I tried "system" and "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: I also tried to verify with data from http://geojson.xyz/ ...unsuccessful using the direct url location

Comment: i'd suggest using 'utf-8' as the encoding, that's the default in 2.18.7 and it works well for github raw links and direct links on geojson.xyz

Comment: Thanks...still the same thing. Are there settings within QGIS that need to be altered?

Comment: Update...I have been testing at work with no luck. I just tried at home and it works! Maybe a firewall setting? Will continue to test and share back...thanks!