# QGIS Plugin server not responding

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis-openlayers-plugin

As of yesterday, the OpenLayers plugin stopped working - as in I could no longer get google, bing or any other background maps. Then in the process of checking and reinstalling the OpenLayers plugin, I found that I could no longer access the QGIS Official Plugin Repository.

I'm on a win64 QGIS 2.18 system.

Is this my local system issue or is there some sort of problem with the QGIS and or OpenLayers systems?  Any ideas on how I can resolve either problem?

Comment: Have you considered using the **QuickMapServices** plugin instead? This also offers basemaps :)

Comment: if this is a machine at work, could it be a proxy has been installed? that might explain why you can't access the plugins repo. see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/25188/55203)

Comment: This is a home office PC so not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct answer because I have not had this issue in the past with basically the same systems and settings in place but the problems seem to be resolved.   I use BitDefender antivirus and ransomware protection.  Bitdefender was picking up some of the file changes QGIS was making and was blocking the program.  I changed the settings to trust QGIS in Bitdefender and it all seems to be working now.